# How do I set the background of my main screen using the .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I can not seem to set the background image for a simple App. I am new to kivy and somewhat new to python. It seems simple but all examples I find use the kv language in the .py file and not the .kv file which i would like to learn how to use.

**start_screen.py**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class StartScreen(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StartScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class TestApp(App):

def build(self):
    return StartScreen()

if __name__=='__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.9

<StartScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'C:\Kivy\graphics\bg.png'
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```

I've read examples of binding needed but is that still needed with the .kv file?
thanks for your help. All the imports are from the buttons an images i had. It would appear, but in the bottom left hand corner. 
thanks again

Comment: What is the problem with your example?

Comment: Screen comes up blank.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that using canvas.Rectangle referencing the background image like 'C:\Kivy\graphics\bg.png' does not work. The only way I could get it to work was to place the image in the same folder as the app. I was able to reference png's using Image and Button widgets but for some reason not the canvas.Rectangle.

```
<StartScreen>:
orientation: 'horizontal'
canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: 'bg.png'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your source in the .kv file should only contain forward slash "/"

```
#:kivy 1.9

<StartScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'C:/Kivy/graphics/bg.png'
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a background color this should be enough (`canvas.before` draws the canvas before the content of the widget):

```
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgb: 1, 0, 0
    Rectangle:
        pos = self.pos
        size = self.size
```

Comment: I am able to change the background color but for some reason i cannot get that png to display.

Comment: Also that rectangle only fills in the bottom left corner. Does not expand the entire window.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `'C:\Kivy\graphics\bg.png'` using 2 backslashes, or use the relative file path, like `'..\\graphics\\bg.png'` also using 2 backslashes together